# How to import two seeds into one ledger hardware?

Tags: ledger-nano-s

I have two 12-word seeds from metamask, how can I import them both into my ledger hardware? Whether I must buy two devices?

Comment: Any idea for this question?

Comment: Did you try asking to Ledger customer support?